# How can I map the data from table in R

Tags: r

[image: Education_table]

As you can see on the image.
Table shows relationship between education(factor), and education_num(int).
Simply, Preschool is 1 as education_num
1st-4th is 2 as education_num
and so on
Doctorate is 16 as education_num.
The problem is I would like to make new table which maps education and education_num.
That is,
It look like

preschool 1

1s4- 4th  2

and so on

Doctorate 16

I thought I needed to use cut() or added option in table(), but I don't know how to make that.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example using `dput()`. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: 1) reproducible example (2) research effort

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have the original dataframe census, in a form like that:

```
> df <- data.frame(education=c("pre","pre","1st-4th","5th-6th","1st-4th"),education_num=c(1,1,2,3,2))

> df
  education education_num
1       pre             1
2       pre             1
3   1st-4th             2
4   5th-6th             3
5   1st-4th             2
```

So you can get unique values:

```
> unique(df)
  education education_num
1       pre             1
3   1st-4th             2
4   5th-6th             3
```

or if you have other columns in the dataframe, you can use:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(education) %>%
    summarise(education_num=unique(education_num)) %>% 
    arrange(education_num)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  education education_num
     <fctr>         <dbl>
1       pre             1
2   1st-4th             2
3   5th-6th             3
```

**EDIT**

If you want to transform from the table, you can use the following:

```
df <- data.frame(education=c("pre","pre","1st-4th","5th-6th","1st-4th"),education_num=c(1,1,2,3,2))

kk <- table(df$education,df$education_num)

> kk

          1 2 3
  1st-4th 0 2 0
  5th-6th 0 0 1
  pre     2 0 0

dfx <- data.frame(edu=row.names(kk)) %>% 
        mutate(edu_num=sapply(edu, function(x) which(kk[x,]>0)))

> dfx
      edu edu_num
1 1st-4th       2
2 5th-6th       3
3     pre       1
```

Comment: First of all, Thanks for kind answer.
Well, what I asked was not how to get each values but 
how to transform from above table to table which you made on your answer

Comment: That helps me a lot. I implemented other ways since I know how to.
but I just want to know whether there was short-cut for that work.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice one OmaymaS!!